# How to implement a timer for every second with zero nanosecond with liburing?

Tags: c, linux

I noticed the io_uring kernel side uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC at [CLOCK_MONOTONIC](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e99332e7b4cda6e60f5b5916cf9943a79dbef902/fs/io_uring.c#L4696-L4701), so for the first timer, I get the time with both CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC and adjust the nanosecond like below and use IORING_TIMEOUT_ABS flag for io_uring_prep_timeout. [iorn/clock.c at master · hnakamur/iorn](https://github.com/hnakamur/iorn/blob/17f649202e7fd6ad7417d3abf3bd70ee0c08e7e4/examples/clock.c#L41-L79)

```
const long sec_in_nsec = 1000000000;

static int queue_timeout(iorn_queue_t *queue) {
    iorn_timeout_op_t *op = calloc(1, sizeof(*op));
    if (op == NULL) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    struct timespec rts;
    int ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &rts);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "clock_gettime CLOCK_REALTIME error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -errno;
    }
    long nsec_diff = sec_in_nsec - rts.tv_nsec;

    ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &op->ts);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "clock_gettime CLOCK_MONOTONIC error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -errno;
    }

    op->handler = on_timeout;
    op->ts.tv_sec++;
    op->ts.tv_nsec += nsec_diff;
    if (op->ts.tv_nsec > sec_in_nsec) {
        op->ts.tv_sec++;
        op->ts.tv_nsec -= sec_in_nsec;
    }
    op->count = 1;
    op->flags = IORING_TIMEOUT_ABS;

    ret = iorn_prep_timeout(queue, op);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return ret;
    }

    return iorn_submit(queue); 
}
```

From the second time, I just increment the second part tv_sec and use IORING_TIMEOUT_ABS flag for io_uring_prep_timeout.

Here is the output from my example program. The millisecond part is zero but it is about 400 microsecond later than just second.

```
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:42.000442
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:43.000371
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:44.000368
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:45.000372
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:46.000372
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:47.000373
on_timeout time=2020-05-10T14:49:48.000373
```

Could you tell me a better way than this?

Comment: linux is not a real time OS, and do not print exactly the time the timer sing

Comment: Anything takes time, including getting the current time. What kind of precision do you need?

Comment: 0.4 milli second on a non real time OS is like 0

Comment: What you're doing is actually incorrect. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, by itself, is the way to go. `IORING_TIMEOUT_ABS` is _only_ if you use `CLOCK_REALTIME`. Use one or the other but don't diff them. See the man page. They use the same timebase and the only difference is whether the clock can jump due to operator setting the time with the `date` command. So, just use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` but set `flags` to 0. You're actually introducing extra error by calling `clock_gettime` twice. What happens if you are timesliced away between calls?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I'd like to update the current time for logging like [ngx_time_update()](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/41ecd45a5bb78b2214c4515768a51aff0c57eead/src/core/ngx_times.c#L80-L192).
I modified my example to use just `CLOCK_REALTIME`, but still about 400 microseconds late.
https://github.com/hnakamur/iorn/commit/936485b573bad78681216c871f7dd588bd297c67
Does it mean `clock_gettime` takes about 400 nanoseconds on my machine?

Comment: I tried to measure the time elapsed for clock_gettime by calling it twice in a row and adjust the timer wait by subtracting the elapsed time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714203/how-to-implement-a-timer-for-every-second-with-zero-nanosecond-with-liburing?noredirect=1#comment109163554_61714203
However the elapsed time for clock_gettime is about 270 nanoseconds and the timer is about 400 microseconds late, that means no improvement over the previous version. So is https://github.com/hnakamur/iorn/commit/936485b573bad78681216c871f7dd588bd297c67 the best I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks for your comments! I'd like to update the current time for logging like `ngx_time_update()`. I modified my example to use just `CLOCK_REALTIME`, but still about 400 microseconds late. github.com/hnakamur/iorn/commit/… Does it mean `clock_gettime` takes about 400 nanoseconds on my machine?

Yes, that sounds about right, sort of. But, *if* you're on an `x86` PC under linux, 400 ns for `clock_gettime` overhead may be a bit high (order of magnitude higher--see below). If you're on an `arm` CPU (e.g. Raspberry Pi, `nvidia` Jetson), it might be okay.

I don't know how you're getting 400 microseconds. But, I've had to do a lot of realtime stuff under linux, and 400 us is similar to what I've measured as the overhead to do a context switch and/or wakeup a process/thread after a syscall suspends it.

I never use `gettimeofday` anymore. I now just use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)` because it's the same except you get nanoseconds instead of microseconds.

Just so you know, although `clock_gettime` is a syscall, nowadays, on most systems, it uses the `VDSO` layer. The kernel injects special code into the userspace app, so that it is able to access the time directly *without* the overhead of a `syscall`.

If you're interested, you could run under `gdb` and disassemble the code to see that it just accesses some special memory locations instead of doing a syscall.

I don't think you need to worry about this too much. Just use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` and set `flags` to 0. The overhead doesn't factor into this, for the purposes of the `ioring` call as your `iorn` layer is using it.

When I do this sort of thing, and I want/need to calculate the overhead of `clock_gettime` itself, I call `clock_gettime` in a loop (e.g. 1000 times), and try to keep the total time below a [possible] timeslice. I use the *minimum* diff between times in each iteration. That compensates for any [possible] timeslicing.

The minimum is the overhead of the call itself [on average].

There are additional tricks that you can do to minimize latency in userspace (e.g. raising process priority, clamping CPU affinity and I/O interrupt affinity), but they can involve a few more things, and, if you're not *very* careful, they can produce worse results.

Before you start taking extraordinary measures, you should have a solid methodology to measure timing/benchmarking to *prove* that your results can *not* meet your timing/throughput/latency *requirements*. Otherwise, you're doing complicated things for no real/measurable/necessary benefit.

---

Below is some code I just created, simplified, but based on code I already have/use to calibrate the overhead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ITERMAX     10000

typedef long long tsc_t;

// tscget -- get time in nanoseconds
static inline tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

// tscsec -- convert nanoseconds to fractional seconds
double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

tsc_t
calibrate(void)
{
    tsc_t tscbeg;
    tsc_t tscold;
    tsc_t tscnow;
    tsc_t tscdif;
    tsc_t tscmin;
    int iter;

    tscmin = 1LL << 62;
    tscbeg = tscget();
    tscold = tscbeg;

    for (iter = ITERMAX;  iter > 0;  --iter) {
        tscnow = tscget();

        tscdif = tscnow - tscold;
        if (tscdif < tscmin)
            tscmin = tscdif;

        tscold = tscnow;
    }

    tscdif = tscnow - tscbeg;

    printf("MIN:%.9f TOT:%.9f AVG:%.9f\n",
        tscsec(tscmin),tscsec(tscdif),tscsec(tscnow - tscbeg) / ITERMAX);

    return tscmin;
}

int
main(void)
{

    calibrate();

    return 0;
}
```

---

On my system, a 2.67GHz Core i7, the output is:

```
MIN:0.000000019 TOT:0.000254999 AVG:0.000000025
```

So, I'm getting 25 ns overhead [and *not* 400 ns]. But, again, each system can be different to some extent.

---

**UPDATE:**

Note that `x86` processors have "speed step". The OS can adjust the CPU frequency up or down semi-automatically. Lower speeds conserve power. Higher speeds are maximum performance.

This is done with a heuristic (e.g. if the OS detects that the process is a heavy CPU user, it will up the speed).

To force maximum speed, linux has this directory:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/cpufreq
```

Where `N` is the cpu number (e.g. 0-7)

Under this directory, there are a number of files of interest. They should be self explanatory.

In particular, look at `scaling_governor`. It has either `ondemand` [kernel will adjust as needed] or `performance` [kernel will force maximum CPU speed].

To force maximum speed, as root, set this [once] to `performance` (e.g.):

```
echo "performance" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Do this for all cpus.

However, I just did this on my system, and it had little effect. So, the kernel's heuristic may have improved.

---

As to the 400us, when a process has been waiting on something, when it is "woken up", this is a two step process.

The process is marked "runnable".

At some point, the system/CPU does a reschedule. The process will be run, based upon the scheduling policy and the process priority in effect.

For many syscalls, the reschedule [only] occurs on the next system timer/clock tick/interrupt. So, for some, there can be a delay of up to a full clock tick (i.e.) for `HZ` value of 1000, this can be up to 1ms (1000 us) later.

On average, this is one half of `HZ` or 500 us.

For *some* syscalls, when the process is marked runnable, a reschedule is done *immediately*. If the process has a higher priority, it will be run immediately.

When I first looked at this [circa 2004], I looked at all code paths in the kernel, and the only syscall that did the immediate reschedule was SysV IPC, for `msgsnd/msgrcv`. That is, when process A did `msgsnd`, any process B waiting for the given message would be run.

But, others did not (e.g. `futex`). They would wait for the timer tick. A lot has changed since then, and now, more syscalls will do the immediate reschedule. For example, I recently measured `futex` [invoked via `pthread_mutex_*`], and it seemed to do the quick reschedule.

Also, the kernel scheduler has changed. The newer scheduler can wakeup/run some things on a fraction of a clock tick.

So, for you, the 400 us, is [possibly] the alignment to the next clock tick.

*But*, it *could* just be the overhead of doing the syscall. To test that, I modified my test program to open `/dev/null` [and/or `/dev/zero`], and added `read(fd,buf,1)` to the test loop.

I got a `MIN:` value of 529 us. So, the delay you're getting could just be the amount of time it takes to do the task switch.

This is what I would call "good enough for now".

To get "razor's edge" response, you'd probably have to write a custom kernel driver and have the driver do this. This is what embedded systems would do if (e.g.) they had to toggle a `GPIO` pin on every interval.

But, if all you're doing is `printf`, the overhead of `printf` and the underlying `write(1,...)` tends to swamp the actual delay.

Also, note that when you do `printf`, it builds the output buffer and when the buffer in `FILE *stdout` is full, it flushes via `write`.

For best performance, it's better to do `int len = sprintf(buf,"current time is ..."); write(1,buf,len);`

Also, when you do this, if the *kernel* buffers for TTY I/O get filled [which is quite possible given the high frequency of messages you're doing], the process will be suspended until the I/O has been sent to the TTY device.

To do this well, you'd have to watch how much space is available, and skip some messages if there isn't enough space to [wholy] contain them.

You'd need to do: `ioctl(1,TIOCOUTQ,...)` to get the available space and skip some messages if it is less than the size of the message you want to output (e.g. the `len` value above).

For your usage, you're probably more interested in the *latest* time message, rather than outputting *all* messages [which would eventually produce a lag]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed thorough comment!
On my system, a 1.99GHz Celeron J1900, the output is:
```
MIN:0.000000131 TOT:0.001387039 AVG:0.000000139
```

On another system, a 3.20GHz Core i5, the output is:
```
MIN:0.000000067 TOT:0.000787530 AVG:0.000000079
```

Comment: Then I wrote a version using nanosleep to trying to print a realtime clock nanosecond on every second.
https://gist.github.com/hnakamur/4246f57ee0d1eaa3224e40a46620c56b

My Celeron system prints about 400 us and my Core i5 system print about 150 us.

So I now agree 0.4 ms delay is like 0 on my system, as bruno says at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714203/how-to-implement-a-timer-for-every-second-with-zero-nanosecond-with-liburing?noredirect=1#comment109162446_61714203